# How to fix 'FHIRValidationError' from fhirclient-4.0.0 prepare() method in python?

Tags: python, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm testing out `fhirclient 4.0.0` (`Python 3.7`) with hapi R4 server

```py
settings = {
    'app_id': 'fhir',
#     'api_base': 'http://test.fhir.org/r4'
    'api_base': 'http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4'
}
smart = client.FHIRClient(settings=settings)    

# capabilitystatement.CapabilityStatement.read_from('metadata', smart.server)
smart.prepare()
```

And I get this validation error

```
FHIRValidationError: {root}:
  rest.0:
    resource.70:
      searchParam.14:
        'Non-optional property "type" on <models.capabilitystatement.CapabilityStatementRestResourceSearchParam object at 0x7fe54cef1668> is missing'
```

Link to capability statement http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/metadata

Does anyone else facing this?

Below is the full trace of the error ..

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FHIRValidationError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-687512ba52eb> in <module>
      7 
      8 # capabilitystatement.CapabilityStatement.read_from('metadata', sof.server)
----> 9 sof.prepare()

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/client.py in prepare(self)
    115             if self.server.ready:
    116                 return True
--> 117             return self.server.prepare()
    118         return False
    119 

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/server.py in prepare(self)
    148         """
    149         if self.auth is None:
--> 150             self.get_capability()
    151         return self.auth.ready if self.auth is not None else False
    152 

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/server.py in get_capability(self, force)
     82             logger.info('Fetching CapabilityStatement from {0}'.format(self.base_uri))
     83             from models import capabilitystatement
---> 84             conf = capabilitystatement.CapabilityStatement.read_from('metadata', self)
     85             self._capability = conf
     86 

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/models/fhirabstractresource.py in read_from(cls, path, server)
    108 
    109         ret = server.request_json(path)
--> 110         instance = cls(jsondict=ret)
    111         instance.origin_server = server
    112         return instance

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/models/capabilitystatement.py in __init__(self, jsondict, strict)
    132         Type `str`. """
    133 
--> 134         super(CapabilityStatement, self).__init__(jsondict=jsondict, strict=strict)
    135 
    136     def elementProperties(self):

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/models/domainresource.py in __init__(self, jsondict, strict)
     40         Type `Narrative` (represented as `dict` in JSON). """
     41 
---> 42         super(DomainResource, self).__init__(jsondict=jsondict, strict=strict)
     43 
     44     def elementProperties(self):

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/models/resource.py in __init__(self, jsondict, strict)
     40         Type `Meta` (represented as `dict` in JSON). """
     41 
---> 42         super(Resource, self).__init__(jsondict=jsondict, strict=strict)
     43 
     44     def elementProperties(self):

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/models/fhirabstractresource.py in __init__(self, jsondict, strict)
     23                 .format(self.__class__, jsondict['resourceType']))
     24 
---> 25         super(FHIRAbstractResource, self).__init__(jsondict=jsondict, strict=strict)
     26 
     27     @classmethod

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/models/fhirabstractbase.py in __init__(self, jsondict, strict)
     64         if jsondict is not None:
     65             if strict:
---> 66                 self.update_with_json(jsondict)
     67             else:
     68                 try:

~/.virtualenvs/fhir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fhirclient/models/fhirabstractbase.py in update_with_json(self, jsondict)
    229 
    230         if len(errs) > 0:
--> 231             raise FHIRValidationError(errs)
    232 
    233     def as_json(self):

FHIRValidationError: {root}:
  rest.0:
    resource.70:
      searchParam.14:
        'Non-optional property "type" on <models.capabilitystatement.CapabilityStatementRestResourceSearchParam object at 0x7fe54cef1668> is missing'
```

Github issue: https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/client-py/issues/79

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HAPI server returns an invalid CapabilityStatement resource, where the type of the searchParam 'near' for Location has not been filled in - I did some checking on that. So the bug is not in your client; actually it works perfectly by telling you what is wrong at the end of the trace, underneath "FHIRValidationError".

Your best option is to reach out to the HAPI server developers and ask them to correct their CapabilityStatement.

Comment: Right. I missed the array index info there. Thanks! I tried this against another public server http://test.fhir.org/r4 and it has same error at a different place. Anyway it's not an issue as I control the server I'm going to use.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, that you are using `fhirclient 4.0.0`? While 4.0.0 is available for more than a year `pip` still has the version `3.2.0.` There is an issue to this here: https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/client-py/issues/70

Using `fhirclient 3.2.0` against a current version of HAPI will result in similar errors. You could either clone fhirclient directly from their github or use a HAPI Server with DSTU3. When hosting your own server you can change the config `hapi.properties` to `fhir_version=DSTU3`.